# mlagent: How to export remote task

Tags: sybase-sql-anywhere, mobilink, sybase-central, mlagent

When creating a new remote tasks via Sybase Central for `mlagent`, it is possible to import task from file.

How to export remote task to a file so it can be imported into another Sybase Central installation (e.g. remote)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tasks are stored inside project folder of MobiLink-project with mlt-extension. They are XML-files. Therefor there is no special export needed. Just copy the file.